# Applying `$invalid` just for visible controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form which shows control depending on property `data-ng-hide="objective.editMode"`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="adduserform">                        
    <div class="form-group">                           
       <label for="title6" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Progress</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">

          <input data-ng-hide="objective.editMode" type="number" min="0" max="100" 
               data-ng-model="newTask.Progress" class="form-control" required  />
          <input data-ng-show="objective.editMode" type="number" min="0" max="100" 
               data-ng-model="objective.Progress" class="form-control" required  />

       </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
             <input data-ng-hide="objective.editMode" type="submit" value="Add" 
                    ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()"/>
             <input data-ng-show="objective.editMode" type="submit" value="Save" 
                    ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="Save()" />    
          </span>                 
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**My question is can `adduserform.$invalid` checks just shown controls on the form?** As `adduserform.$invalid` requires all control to be filled, but not all controls are shown on the form as appearance of control is depending on `objective.editMode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` instead of `ng-hide`:

```
<input data-ng-if="!objective.editMode" type="number" min="0" max="100" 
           data-ng-model="newTask.Progress" class="form-control" required  />
```

Answer (score 1):

elements hidden with `data-ng-hide / data-ng-show` are still on the DOM tree and thus being validated. Use `data-ng-if` instead, which will remove elements from the DOM:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="adduserform">                        
<div class="form-group">                           
   <label for="title6" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Progress</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">

      <input data-ng-if="!objective.editMode" type="number" min="0" max="100" 
           data-ng-model="newTask.Progress" class="form-control" required  />
      <input data-ng-if="objective.editMode" type="number" min="0" max="100" 
           data-ng-model="objective.Progress" class="form-control" required  />

   </div>
</div>    

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <span data-ng-if="!editMode">
         <input data-ng-if="!objective.editMode" type="submit" value="Add" 
                ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()"/>
         <input data-ng-if="objective.editMode" type="submit" value="Save" 
                ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="Save()" />    
      </span>                 
   </div>
</div>
```